# How to know that neovim is started by zsh command "git commit" from my terminal emulator?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lua

As title. I'm building a plugin and this is the last step.

I've configured my .zshrc so that git will use neovim as its texteditor program to enter commit messages in interactive mode. The on-going neovim plugin will do something on VimEnter. I want to exclude any git-triggered VimEnter for my plugin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Git will setup some environment variables when commiting. So in your VimEnter autocommand, you can simply check whether e.g. `$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` exists.

Check the git documentation for possible variables: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_committing

An alternative is, to run the command `:!env` and see what environment variables are exposed to Vim on commiting.